# How to Use Artisan::call() in Command Class

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I have bunch of test classes and I like to call some of them based on their types or logic. I've created a command class to achive that based on the passed parameters.

The following command should find all the test classes that their names contain "Database" and "Test.php".

```
sail artisan testsome database
```

That part works without any issue, and produces an array of classes like:

```
$tests = ['GeneratedDatabaseFileTest', 'StatedDatabaseFileTest'];
```

Then I do this to call each class:

```
foreach ($tests as $testClass) {
    Artisan::call("test --filter {$testClass}");
}
```

But I see this message on the terminal:

```
PHPUnit 9.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Cannot open file "database".
```

I also tried to use

```
exec("sail artisan test --filter {$testClass}");
```

but it didn't work and said

```
sh: 1: sail: not found
```

So, is there a way to run Artisan::call command in Command class, or should I try a different approach to call multiple test classes?

Thanks in advance.